# Observing blur event for select Prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have

```
<div id="myselect">

<select>
<option value="0">1</option>
<option value="1">2</option>
</select>

</div>
```

Im trying to get the value of the select on blur.

So far I have:

```
    Event.observe('#myselect select', 'blur', function(event) {
        //get value
    });
```

Please advise!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
$('myselect').down('select').observe('blur', function(e){
    alert('blur');
});
```

Comment: Why do you specify the .down event?